# iptables: LOG is not a valid target

Tags: iptables, logs, chrome-book

I'm learning to configure firewall rules using iptables. For some reason, iptables does not recognize LOG as a valid target:

`○ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j LOG
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

Extra info:

`` ○ sudo iptables
iptables v1.6.0: no command specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
○ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial ``

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I thought LOG would be a built-in target with iptables. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that this is Ubuntu 16.04 running on my chromebook via Crouton.

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 installation readily available, but does your kernel have the NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG module available (check /proc/config.gz)?

Comment: @ErikF that file does not exist in my ChromeOS chroot.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you don't have `xt_LOG` module installed.
filename:       /lib/modules/x.xx.x-xx-generic/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_LOG.ko
alias:          ip6t_LOG
alias:          ipt_LOG

Check it:

```
lsmod | grep xt_LOG
```

Install/add it:

```
sudo modprobe xt_LOG
```

Also check your kernel config at: `/boot/config-x.xx.x-xx-generic`
If you have `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG` enabled.

Comment: I tried doing sudo modprobe xt_LOG, but it didn't work.

I also checked my /boot/ directory and there are 0 files in there. I guessing this may be due to the fact that I am running this on my chromebook via crouton (which I definitely forgot to mention, my fault. I'll update my question with that information.)

Comment: Not surprising to not have anything in /boot being that Crouton is a `chroot` environment inside of ChomeOS; you're still running on the ChromeOS kernel.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Build-chrome-os-kernel-and-kernel-modules but I have no experience with Crouton on ChromeOS